# How to check whether the tab is active or not in JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

How can I check whether a tab in a JTabbedPane instance is active or not, in the class of the tab (nested class) itself and not in the enclosing class?

I know that there is a method `booloean isEnabledAt(int index);` but this method can only be called in the enclosing class. Whereas I want to check whether the tab is currently selected within the tab class itself (nested class).

Can anybody please suggest how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your component has a [parent](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent()), eventually the `JTabbedPane`. `JTabbedPane` has methods like [`getSelectedIndex()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#getSelectedIndex()) or [`getSelectedComponent()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#getSelectedComponent()).

Comment: Thank u. But How can I call these methods in the nested class of JTabbedPane? as the need is to see whether a tab is selected or not and if it is I have to update the contents by removing old version of a component and replacing it with new one. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 7):

I know that this is old topic, but I found it when looking for a solution to a similar (though slightly different) problem.

To determine what tab was selected, use a `ChangeEvent` listener. This is a very simple way to perform an action whenever a tab is selected. Hopefully this will help someone else, though this is an old topic.

```
private void zakladkiStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) 
{                                      
    if (zakladki.getTitleAt(zakladki.getSelectedIndex()).equals("tab title here")) 
    {
        // what you wish to do when tab is selected here ....
    }
}
```