# Method to say what jpanel is shown at the moment in a jtabbedpane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I don't find the method that say what jpanel  is showed at the moment, what I see on the screen at the moment. I try isShowing() , hasFocus() , isEnabled() but never that works. Thanks at all.

Comment: `getSelectedIndex() `  , `getSelectedComponent()`  related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145916/get-jtable-from-selected-tab-at-jtabbedpane and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937684/how-to-check-whether-the-tab-is-active-or-not-in-jtabbedpane

Comment: doesn't return the jpanel and myPane.getSelectedComponent().getComponents(); .getComponents() doesn't exist. How can I do?

Comment: i explain your comment problem at the end of my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `getSelectedComponent()` or `getSelectedIndex()` to get currently active panel on jtabbed pane. consider following example this will set color of currently active panel to yello when click the button

```
public class JTabbedPaneDemo extends JFrame {

    public JTabbedPaneDemo() {
        JButton button = new JButton("color");
        JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel();
        JTabbedPane jtbExample = new JTabbedPane();
        JPanel jplInnerPanel1 = new JPanel();
        jtbExample.addTab("t1", jplInnerPanel1);
        jtbExample.setSelectedIndex(0);
        JPanel jplInnerPanel2 = new JPanel();
        jtbExample.addTab("t2", jplInnerPanel2);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtbExample.getSelectedComponent().setBackground(Color.yellow);
            }
        });
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        mainpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainpanel.add(jtbExample, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainpanel.add(button,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.setContentPane(mainpanel);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JTabbedPaneDemo();
    }
}
```

and for your comment

`myPane.getSelectedComponent()` will return active component .and `getSelectedComponent()` return `component` object .so there is no method `getComponents()` in `component` class.if you are going to get all components in jpnel then you have to cast returned component to a `jpanel` before call `getComponents()` example

```
Component[] c=((JPanel)jtbExample.getSelectedComponent()).getComponents();
```

for your comment 2

if you want to verify that active one is jpanel1 then cast to `jpanel` and  check like follow.make sure you have declared jPanel12 as a `field` variable.

```
if((JPanel)jTabbedPane2.getSelectedComponent()==jPanel12){
     System.out.println("jPanel12 is active");
}
```

Comment: Fantastic reply but I have this issue: I have this if condition: " if(jPanel12==jTabbedPane2.getSelectedComponent()) ". I must verify if I stay in the jPanel12 but this condition don't work. What's the trouble in my costruct?